# List all the directories which contain a *.pdf file in linux and pipe the result to a file

Tags: linux, grep

Is there a way in Linux to list all the directories which contain a *.pdf file using something like grep and piping all the results to a file?

The reason why I want to do this is I have  a large static html based site and I want to list all the urls which contain a pdf.

The sites structure is your typical tree structure with many levels and sublevels for this is a small cut down example:

```
public_html/
    content/
        help/
        advice/
        marketing/
             campaign1/
                 pdfs/
             campaign2/
                 pdfs/

    shop/
        templates/
            nav/
                guarantees/
        includes/
etc...
```

I want to search through this structure and the list all the pdfs contained in here and pipe them to a file. The example output would look like below with each new result on a new line:

```
public_html/content/marketing/campaign1/pdfs/example1.pdf
public_html/content/marketing/campaign1/pfds/example2.pdf
public_html/shop/templates/nav/guarantees/guarantee.pdf
```

I would only want the pdfs from the public_html folder. I wouldn't want to search through my home, bin, tmp, var etc... folders on the hard drive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this through find command,

```
find /public_html -mindepth 1 -iname "*.pdf" -type f > output-file
```

**Explanation:**

```
/public_html     # Directory on which the find operation is going to takesplace.

-mindepth 1      # If mindepth is set to 1, it will search inside subdirectories also.

-iname "*.pdf"   # Name must end with .pdf.

-type f          # Only files.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would help

**find "Directory" | grep .pdf> outputfile**

example : find Desktop/|grep pdf > 1.txt